# Scale down NSImage results into pixel change?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm using the following code to scale down my image:

```
NSImage * smallImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, height)];
[smallImage lockFocus];
[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] 
     setImageInterpolation:NSImageInterpolationHigh];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)
         fromRect:NSZeroRect
        operation:NSCompositeCopy
         fraction:1.0];
[smallImage unlockFocus];
```

Basically, this works fine, but if I set the `width` and `height` to exactly as the original one, and compare the images pixel by pixel, there are still some pixels changed.

And since my app is pixel-sensitive, I need to make sure every pixel is correct, so I'm wondering how can I keep pixels as they are during such scale down, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `NSImage` will change the image data in various ways. It attempts to optimize the "payload" image data according to the size needed for its graphical representation on the UI.

Scaling it down and up again is generally not a good idea.

AFAIK you can only avoid that by keeping the original image data somehere else (e.g. on disk or in a separate `NSData` container or so). 
If you need to apply calcluations or manipulations on the image data which needs to be 100% accurate down to each pixel, then work with `NSData` or C strings/byte arrays only. Avoid `NSImage` unless
a) the result is for presentations on the device only
b) you really need functionality that comes with NSImage objects.

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining the problems in principle, not scientific.
Pixels have a fixed size, for technical reasons.

No, you can't keep your pixels, when scaling down.

An example to explain: Pixelsize in square 0,25 inch. Now you want to fill a square wich 1,1 inch. It's impossible. How many pixels should be used? 4 = too less, 5 too much. Now in the COCOA libs or wherever it happens, a decision is made: better more pixels = enlarging square size, or less = reducing square size. That's out of control for you.

Another problem is - also out of control for you - the way how measures are computed.
An example: 1 inch is nearly 2.54 cm, so 1.27 is 0.5 inch, but what is 1.25 cm? Values, not only measures are internally computed using one measure-unit: I think it's inch (as DOUBLE, with fixed number of digits after the period). When using the unit cm it is internally recomputed in inch, some mathematical operations are done (e.g. How many pixels are neccessary for the square?) and the result is sent back, maybe recomputed in cm. That also happens when using INTEGER, internally computed as DOUBLE and returned as INTEGERS. Funny things = unexpected values happen from that, especially after divisions, which are used for scaling down!

By the way: If an image is scaled, often new pixels are created for the scaled image. For example, if you have 4 pixels: 2 red, 2 blue, the new ONE has a mixed color, somehow violet. There is no way back. So always work on copies of an image!